# Is it possible to have triggers (like SQL triggers) in DynamoDB?

Tags: triggers, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to have an action triggered every time an item is created or updated on a DynamoDB. I have been going through the doc, but cannot find anything like this. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  DynamoDB doesn't let you run any code server-side.  The only thing which might count as server-side actions as part of an update are conditional updates, but those can't trigger changes to other items.

Answer (score 1):

The new update supports triggers.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-triggers-streams-lambda-cross-region-replication-app/

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use DynamoDb Streams.

A stream consists of stream records. Each stream record represents a single data modification in the DynamoDB table to which the stream belongs. Each stream record is assigned a sequence number, reflecting the order in which the record was published to the stream.

Stream records are organized into groups, or shards. Each shard acts as a container for multiple stream records, and contains information required for accessing and iterating through these records. The stream records within a shard are removed automatically after 24 hours.

The relative ordering of a sequence of changes made to a single primary key will be preserved within a shard. Further, a given key will be present in at most one of a set of sibling shards that are active at a given point in time. As a result, your code can simply process the stream records within a shard in order to accurately track changes to an item.

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://zapier.com/help/dynamodb might be what you are looking for.

Comment: how is this related to DynamoDB trigger? irrelevant advertizing?

Comment: OK, seem to only support create, but not update. And with all the required restrictions on the table, I can probably write a small piece of code to scan by time to figure out the changes myself.

Comment: probably still didn't require the down vote ... hey but whatever floats your boat Kenneth ...